# Changing values to combobox from an array

Tags: javafx

I need to load values from an array to a combobox, with this code it loads only the last value of the array? Can anyone help me please.

```
for(int i =0; i<lines.size(); i++) {
    resultArray[i] = lines.get(i).split("\t");

    Laptops[i] = resultArray[i][0];
    ObservableList<String> option = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Laptops[i].toString());

    cbx1.setValue("");
    cbx1.setItems(option);

    cbx2.setValue("");
    cbx2.setItems(option);

    cbx3.setValue("");
    cbx3.setItems(option);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing. But intuitively it seems you're assigning values to cbx1, cxb2 and cbx3, and then reassigning them with every loop. I suggest making a list of your cbxs, selecting one per iteration, and only use setItems once for each cbx.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, you are creating a brand new `List` on each iteration. So when you call `setItems()` on your `ComboBox`, the `option` list only has that one item in it.

There are several other issues with your loop, but once you have a valid array, populating a `ComboBox` with it is quite simple using the `Arrays.asList()` method:

```
ObservableList<String> option = FXCollections.observableList(Arrays.asList(resultArray));
cbx1.setItems(option);
```

---

That being said, I doubt you're getting a proper array with your line:

```
resultArray[i] = lines.get(i).split("\t");
```

Without knowing what `lines` actually is in your code, it's difficult to address this specifically, but it looks like you could skip the whole `resultArray` altogether and just use `lines`.

Calling the `split()` method **returns** an array of Strings anyway. Perhaps you could remove the loop altogether and just try:

```
ObservableList<String> options = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(lines.split("\t"));
```